# IIS: Setting a script map on "Web Sites" node

Tags: php, iis, installation

Regarding setting up script maps on IIS, I am wondering what happens if I create a script map for `.php` files to `C:\php\php.exe` on the `Web Sites` node. Do all websites below the `web Sites` node, including the `Default Website` inherit the setting or do I manually have to add the script map to all 29 websites below the `Web Sites` node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scriptmaps are inherited down through the site and virtual directory level. However inheritance can be broken by setting a scriptmap at a site or directory level. Once inheritance is broken, changes to the root will no longer affect these sites or directories.

Comment: Is there a way to (i) enforce propagation of changes when you make a change on `Web Sites` node (ii) enforce inheritance on an individual website just to be sure all things are in sync?

Comment: Yes you can enforce propagation. In IIS manager, when you make a change to a script mapping you will be prompted to select child nodes where you want the change to apply.